# Reading an encrypted zipped .obb file

Tags: android, encryption, apk, apk-expansion-files

I have two files (for example) that I want to put in my apk main expansion file. Let these files be *img1.jpg* and *img2.jpg*. I compress them using the following command:

```
zip -n .jpg main.123.in.example.app.obb *.jpg
```

(The version code is 123 and the package is in.example.app). This creates an obb file: *main.123.in.example.app.obb*

I place this code on an appropriate path. I can access the files *img1.jpg* and *img2.jpg* easily by calling the following:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File expPath = new File(root.toString() + "/Android/obb/in.example.app");
String pathToObb = expPath + File.separator + "main.123.in.example.app.obb";
ZipResourceFile zip = new ZipResourceFile(pathToObb);
InputStream iStream = zip.getInputStream("img1.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream, null, options);// options to decode
```

This works perfectly. Now, how does one read an encrypted zip file created using the following:

```
zip -n -encrypt .jpg main.123.in.example.app.obb *.jpg
```

Is there any way we can read such an encrypted zip file? Or do we resort to the [jobb tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html) to do the encryption and use [StorageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html) to mount encrypted obb and read from there?